# Render boolean column as true/false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using Jquery Datatables v1.10 in ASP.NET MVC 5 project. I have a boolean field in the model which is rendered as checkbox in datatable. My issue is I want it as true/false instead of checkbox so that I can compare that value in `createdRow` event and assign some CSS to a row based on value in boolean field.

I am not able to figure out a way to get true/false instead of `input type='checkbox' />` as data. Any inputs please.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tableTest").dataTable({           
        "createdRow": function (row, data, dataIndex) {
            debugger;
            if (data[7] == "false") { 
               //instead of false I am getting <input class="check-box" disabled="disabled" type="checkbox">" here
                $(row).addClass('important');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is this your full code ? are you using any column rendering ? I tried  a datatable  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/socma0bd/) the table renders fine.

Comment: You are right, your code helped to figure out the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was using `@Html.DisplayFor` to render the boolean field which returned checkbox. Once I removed it I was able to get actual true and false as values.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `createdRow` callback for this. Instead, configure the [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) method for the appropriate column. It is good practice to configure all columns.

```
 $("#tableTest").dataTable({           
         columns: [
              null, // first column, nothing special configured
              null, // 2. column
              null, // 3.
              null, // 4.
              null, // 5.
              null, // 6.
              null, // 7.
              // eigth column (takes data from data[7]):
              {
                  render: function(data) {
                     if (data === false) {
                         return '<div class="important">false</div>';
                     }
                     else {
                         return '<div>true</div>';
                     } 
                  }
              }
         ]
    });
```